# Spurious space after automatic line break before \index in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, indexing, makeindex, makeidx

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}%
\newlength{\myLen}\setlength{\myLen}{33em}%
\noindent 1st line. Plain \(B\), no index:\\
\hspace*{\myLen}\(\Sigma\to B\)\\
\noindent 4th line. Index before plain B:\\
\hspace*{\myLen}\(\Sigma\to \index{B}B\)\\
\noindent 7th line. Index after plain B:\\
\hspace*{\myLen}\(\Sigma\to B\index{B}\)
\printindex
\end{document}
```

to the standard `pdflatex`-`makeindex` loop or `lualatex`-`makeindex` loop produces

[image: output]

As you see, line 6 starts with a spurious horizontal space before .

1. Where does this space come from?
2. How to hack `\index` to remove the spurious horizontal space if we wish to continue using `\index` before the indexed math item (e.g., because some package uses `\index` internally)?

A known workaround is putting `\index` after the indexed term; no question about it.

Similar issue: https://www.dickimaw-books.com/bugtracker.php?key=189 .

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

Reverse the order

```
\Sigma\to B\index{B}
```

as there won't be a line/page break between B and the index entry. Or add braces

```
\Sigma\to{\index{B}B}
```

#### What's the problem?

A minimal example showing the issue, to be compiled with `pdftex` (or also with `tex` to see that it's a problem with the basic tool):

```
\hsize=0pt
\parindent=0pt
\overfullrule=0pt % no distractions
\hfuzz=\maxdimen  % no warnings

\nopagenumbers
\tracingall

$A\to B$

$A\to\special{}B$

\bye
```

[image]

Here's the trace for the first paragraph:

```
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
...\mathon
...\teni A
...\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
...\tensy !
...\penalty 500
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
..\penalty 300
..\glue(\baselineskip) 5.16669
..\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x0.0
...\teni B
...\kern0.50172
...\mathoff
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

and for the second one

```
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
...\mathon
...\teni A
...\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
...\tensy !
...\penalty 500
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
..\penalty 300
..\glue(\baselineskip) 5.16669
..\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x0.0
...\special{}
...\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
...\teni B
...\kern0.50172
...\mathoff
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

You might use `\write-1{}` instead of `\special` and you'd get the same: the main ingredient for this recipe is any *whatsit*.

What happens? The whatsit is ignored as far as automatic computation of math spacing is concerned, so from `A\to\special{}B` you get

**Ord Rel W Ord**

(where **W** stands for ‘whatsit’) but spaces and penalties are inserted as

**Ord** `\thickmuskip` **Rel** `\relpenalty` **W** `\thickmuskip` **Ord**

where `\relpenalty` allows a line break before the whatsit, so it and the space go on the next line, rather than the expected

**Ord** `\thickmuskip` **Rel** `\relpenalty` `\thickmuskip` **W Ord**

The TeXbook is silent about treatment of whatsits in math lists; however the final result makes sense even if unexpected, because glue is attached to math atoms, not to whatsits.

Adding braces around the whatsit will turn it into an **Ord** atom and solve the problem. Including the following symbol in the braces will do as well and is better for the specific case.

However, adding the `\index` command *after* the symbol seems even better, because no line break is allowed there.

Comment: Thanks! How about `\index`ing relations, e.g., certain right arrows? We might need stuff such as, logically speaking, `A\index{A}  \index{myArrow}\to  B\index{B}  \index{myArrow}\to  C\index{C}  \index{myArrow}\to  D\index{D}`.  Where should the various `\index` commands go to avoid spurious-space issues?

Comment: @GeekestGeek I’d say `\mathrel{\index=}=}`

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. `\mathrel{\index=}=}` has one opening { but two closing }.

Comment: @GeekestGeek Sorry, typing on the phone is irksome: `\mathrel{\index{=}=}`.

Answer (score 2):

you can put a brace group around the `\index{...}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}%
\newlength{\myLen}\setlength{\myLen}{33em}%
\noindent 1st line. Plain \(B\), no index:\\
\hspace*{\myLen}\(\Sigma\to B\)\\
\noindent 4th line. Index before plain B:\\
\hspace*{\myLen}\(\Sigma\to {\index{B}}B\)\\
\noindent 7th line. Index after plain B:\\
\hspace*{\myLen}\(\Sigma\to B\index{B}\)
\printindex
\end{document}
```

when used in this context the `\write` node ends up allowing a line break between the arrow and the `\thickmuskip` that follows it so you get a thickmuskip at the start of the line.

Comment: I don't think that's the cause, because `\@bsphack` does nothing in math mode. If I change `\index{B}` into `\special{}`, then the behavior is the same. It's the whatsit that ruins the business.

Comment: @egreg well yes it;s the whatsit in the end but I was thinking it''s moved the space but I guess not, I'll reword

Comment: Thanks! Putting braces around the whole thing, as in `{\index{B}B}`, would work too, wouldn't it? Or are there any adverse effects when compared to `{\index{B}}B`?